# Hibernate application is not executing because XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This is the error that I am getting:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 29 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml] is invalid
```

This is the code in sdnext.xml:

```
27:<bean id="dataSource"
28: class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
29:        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
30:        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/madhavi</property>
31:        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
32:        <property name="connection.password">madhu1301</property>
33: </bean>
```

I added all jar files.

What is the problem? Why it is giving error?

Comment: thanks. but <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> is worked.

Comment: If the answer you were given was useful, accept it. If you found the solution yourself, you can write your own answer to help others with the same question, or close your question. The comment you wrote is not helpful to others using StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the schema here: property must have a name attribute followed by a value or ref attribute.

Plus, property names are incorrect here. You should look at the driver class API

Should be:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/madhavi/"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="madhu1301"/>
</bean>
```

Anyway, for a more concise and shorter XML file, you should use the `p` namespace.

One last thing. Quoting from the javadoc api:

> NOTE: This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not actually pool Connections. It just serves as simple replacement for a full-blown connection pool, implementing the same standard interface, but creating new Connections on every call.
>
> Useful for test or standalone environments outside of a J2EE container, either as a DataSource bean in a corresponding ApplicationContext or in conjunction with a simple JNDI environment. Pool-assuming Connection.close() calls will simply close the Connection, so any DataSource-aware persistence code should work.